# Webpack/Angular CLI - how to embed scripts in HTML instead of referencing them?

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

I'm building a lean Angular app that should be ran locally through `file://` URL.
The `index.html` file will be attached and deployed through a headless browser and I cannot use a HTTP server as a solution. Running the file locally would bring up Cross Origin errors as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752055/cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-http-error-when-loading-a-local).

The solution I came up with, which works (!) is to replace all `<script src="..."/>` resources (which are bundled with `ng build --prod`) with `<script>...</script>`. At the moment, I'm doing it **manually**.

With the output `index.html` from my `ng build` being:

```
<script src="runtime-es2015.1eba213af0b233498d9d.js" type="module"></script><script src="runtime-es5.1eba213af0b233498d9d.js" nomodule defer></script><script src="polyfills-es5.9e286f6d9247438cbb02.js" nomodule defer></script><script src="polyfills-es2015.690002c25ea8557bb4b0.js" type="module"></script><script src="main-es2015.3bdd714db04c3d863447.js" type="module"></script><script src="main-es5.3bdd714db04c3d863447.js" nomodule defer></script>
```

I'm changing it to:

```
<script type="module">//content of runtime-es2015.1eba213af0b233498d9d.js//</script><script nomodule defer>//content of runtime-es5.1eba213af0b233498d9d.js//</script><script nomodule defer>//content of polyfills-es5.9e286f6d9247438cbb02.js//</script><script type="module">//content of polyfills-es2015.690002c25ea8557bb4b0.js//</script><script type="module">//content of main-es2015.3bdd714db04c3d863447.js//</script><script nomodule defer>//content of main-es5.3bdd714db04c3d863447.js//</script>
```

I'm looking for a way to automate it through the build script.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you consider creating a custom script that parse index.html and looks for Angular generated bundles and delete them, then go to dist folder and then read the content of only those generates scripts and pushes its content script tags to index.html? all this process will be done in Build time, you could add package script: `ng build && node customScript.js`

Comment: @RazRonen yes, I'm currently trying to make it with a `gulp` script, I'll answer my on question in the end if no other solutions offered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution I eventually came up with with `gulp`:

I've ran `npm install --save-dev` to packages `gulp`, `gulp-inline` and `del`.

After creating a `gulpfile.js` to the root directory, I've wrote the following code:

```
let gulp = require('gulp');
let inline = require('gulp-inline');
let del = require('del');

gulp.task('inline', function (done) {
    gulp.src('dist/index.html')
    .pipe(inline({
        base: 'dist/',
        disabledTypes: 'css, svg, img'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/').on('finish', function(){
        done()
    }));
});

gulp.task('clean', function (done) {
    del(['dist/*.js'])
    done()
});

gulp.task('bundle-for-local', gulp.series('inline', 'clean'))
```

The task `inline` will replace all `<script src="..."></script>` with the corresponding file content.
`clean` would then delete all of the `.js` files.

Finally, I've updated my `package.json` with a new build script:

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build-for-local": "ng build --prod --aot && gulp bundle-for-local",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
```

Now `npm run build-for-local` will do the work.